# vim 7.3 upgrade sets runtimepath to nonexistent path

Tags: vim, pathogen

Hi i have vim6 and upgraded to vim7.

I have both versions.  vim6 runs fine.

Upgraded vim7 runtimepath has
`/usr/local/share/vim/...`  this path does not exist, contain anyfiles

I am trying to get the colorscheme to work.  When I set syntax on, I get that `/usr/local/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim` not found error.

So i found the syntax.vim at `~/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim`
So I updated the runtimepath using
`execute pathogen#infect('bundle/{}', '~/vim/runtime/{}')`

the old vim still works, and has updated runtimepath.  the new vim73 still has the updated runtimepaths , but when on syntax on it gives an error looking for the file at the old path that never existed.

so how do i remove path from the runtimepath

i also
thanks

## edit

upgrade was to 7.4 from 7.3.547

compiled with python as follows:
`./configure --enable-pythoninterp --with-features=huge --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/`

`make`

## hack

whats wrong with just ln -s ~/vim/runtime/ /usr/local/share/vim/ ?
or just copy the file that i need to get syntax, and hopefully color ..

Comment: How did you compile vim that path is set when you compile. It is also filled in when you do `make install`. (Note 7.4 is current)

Comment: compile required a special config

Comment: You didn't do `make install` or set the prefix (if you want to change where vim installs to)

Comment: yup thats the prob!! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a path of `/usr/local/share/...`, it looks like you've compiled Vim yourself from the sources. `sudo make install` should have taken care of the copying of the runtime files to that location. What you did with Pathogen is definitely **not** the right way to fix it.

Unless you're on a very old or poorly maintained Linux distribution, it should be possible to obtain a current Vim package (that is, a 7.4 version) through your distribution's package manager (on Debian-based systems, it's commonly called *vim-gnome*). Unless you need to have the bleeding edge version (unlikely in your case with the former Vim 6), or incorporate custom patches, that is the easy and recommended approach.